# Not finding correct position of an element in the page. Function is not considering paddings

Tags: javascript, position, padding

I've been trying to find good functions to help me placing the elements in the page, considering other element's positions. I'm not using jQuery.

So I found a lot of sources telling me that I should navigate trought the offsetParent's of the target element, getting their offsetTops and offsetLefts. It almost working, but I made a few tests and realized that it's not considering the padding of some parents. I changed the padding using CSS and it still gives the same number. And when I place the element in the page, it gets stuck closer or over the parent's margins

I'm using this function (and it's pretty similar to most functions I found around the web)

```
function getOffset(el){
if(isString(el)) el = document.getElementById(el);

var x = el.offsetLeft;
var y = el.offsetTop;

while(el = el.offsetParent){
    x += el.offsetLeft;
    y += el.offsetTop;
}

return { left: x, top: y };
```

}

Do you know how to fix it, friends? Does it help if I post some pictures? I've already tried to change the css and i'm conviced that the problem is the padding of one element.

@EDIT

I'm using Firefox 14.0.1

In the original page there are many other elements, and that's why the number I get is different. But the error is the same in jsfiddle. It says 1 to left (that is probably the width of the border of the element 'Content'). It is not considering the 15 pixels of left padding in the element 'registerArea', neither considering its border.

http://jsfiddle.net/rhPYH/25/

Comment: Note that jQuery has the same limitation, per their docs: "Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element."

Comment: ahh is it some sort of an impossible thing to do, Steve? have you ever seen this same problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I've been using the display: table to make the size of an element autoadjust to it's content. For some reason, Javascript aws having some problems to find the correct size of this element 'registerArea' (which had a **display: table rule and paddings**). What I did was **changing the display for block**. it's still rendering correctly the element, and now Javascript is taking the paddings into account, what is giving me the correct position of the element.